# How to delete all files in fdupes -rd instance?

Tags: filesystems, fdupes

I run

```
fdupes -rd /home/masi/Documents/
```

I get files from my old editor (TexPad of OSX) in many folders which I do not need:

```
[1] /home/masi/Documents/.texpadtmp/pirkanmaa.out
[2] /home/masi/Documents/.texpadtmp/pirkanmaa2.out
[3] /home/masi/Documents/.texpadtmp/pirkanmaa3.out

Set 258 of 2664, preserve files [1 - 3, all]: 3

   [-] /home/masi/Documents/.texpadtmp/pirkanmaa.out
   [-] /home/masi/Documents/.texpadtmp/pirkanmaa2.out
   [+] /home/masi/Documents/.texpadtmp/pirkanmaa3.out
```

There are only options `[1-3, all]` but I want to delete all those files in the interactive mode. 
How can you delete all options in fdupes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fdupes` delete option is meant for just deleting duplicates. It requires that you preserve at least one of the duplicate files because once it deletes every duplicate but one, that last one is no longer a duplicate, so it is out of `fdupes` domain.

Having said that, there are times when you want to delete all files anyway. So I made a patch to `fdupes` that adds a `none!` option at the preserve prompt. The `fdupes` maintainers will have to decide whether or not to accept this patch, but in the meantime, you can build it yourself if your machine is set up for development:

```
git clone -b preserve-none git@github.com:Motardo/fdupes.git
cd fdupes
make fdupes
sudo make install
```

Comment: Here the situation in the main tree https://github.com/adrianlopezroche/fdupes/pull/28.patch and https://github.com/adrianlopezroche/fdupes/pull/28.diff for All to review.